# Can't disable Privacy Extensions for IPv6

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, sysctl

On a fresh Debian 12 install, I wish to disable Privacy Extention for IPv6, but the config get rewritten every time I reboot.

After doing the proper modification to `/etc/sysctl.conf` I'm getting the desired config:

```
# /sbin/sysctl -a | grep use_tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp5s0.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.use_tempaddr = 0
```

But after reboot, I'm back with the initial configuration:

```
# /sbin/sysctl -a | grep use_tempaddr
net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp5s0.use_tempaddr = 2
net.ipv6.conf.lo.use_tempaddr = -1
net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.use_tempaddr = 0
```

I've found suggestions that network-manager might be interfering, but disabling `ipv6.ip6-privacy` sticks after reboot and doesn't change anything.

Any idea on what could be rewriting my sysctl configuration ?

Comment: I'm using Debian 12 too but I don't have Privacy Extensions enabled by default. However my install is far from "fresh". Any chance it could be from `/etc/systemd/network*`?

Comment: After some more grepping around, it seems I had edited the wrong interface with `nmcli` which was indeed the source of interference with `sysctl`. Editing `ipv6.ip6-privacy` for the right interface actually worked.